# Can I declare myself section in assembly source code and ld script?

Tags: linux, assembly, linker, elf

I know

- In assembly language source code, I can use directives `.text`, `.data`, or `.rodata` to declare sections.
- In linker script, I can use following commands to generate sections into ELF file

> ```
> .text : { *(.text) }
> .data : { *(.data) }
> ```

- If using readelf, I can see sections `.text`, `.data`, etc.

My questions are:

- Can I add a custom section `.mysection` to ELF by asm code and ld script?
- If I add custom section and build project as a shared library, can linux dynamic linker/loader deal with my shared lib correctly? Or I have to modify dyn-linker/loader?

Appreciate any suggesions.

Comment: Yes and yes. Why haven't you just tried it?

Comment: @Jester I had a try. But it failed with error "reset.S: Assembler messages:
reset.S:8: Error: unknown pseudo-op: `.mysection'"

Comment: Use the `.section` directive when creating your own named sections.

Answer (score 0):

I am summarizing the comments from @Jester @Ross Ridge on question for reference

Yes you can add customize section (with out changing the kernel dynamic loader as it will determine the sections from the ELF headers)
you should use .section directive to avoid the error "reset.S: Assembler messages: reset.S:8: Error: unknown pseudo-op: `.mysection".